# How to change static variable in partial class when application settings update?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Modal form in which users can enter database connection strings. And on the main form, it gets the value of the string that has been entered on the Modal form.

Problem is, when I change a setting within the modal form and save it, it doesn't update while the program is running. The program has to restart before the changes to take effect.

```
public partial class EbayListing : Form
{
    static string DBServer = Properties.Settings.Default.DBServer;
    static string DBName = Properties.Settings.Default.DBName;
    static string UName = Properties.Settings.Default.UName;
    static string PWord = Properties.Settings.Default.PWord;

    static string conString = "SERVER=" + DBServer + ";" + "DATABASE=" + DBName + ";" + "UID=" + UName + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + PWord + ";";

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
    MySqlCommand cmd;
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
}
```

I need the static strings to update each time the settings change from the modal form.

Comment: You could implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? and then on change, you could update your db connection to use it.

Comment: why don't you use the standard connection string mechanism?

Comment: don't make it static. just use it just in time.

Comment: The main problem here is using static fields and assigning values in declaration. So values will only assign the first time your form is created.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and when one of the strings changes, you update the appropriate part of your static variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a property

```
static string conString
{
   get
   {
       return "SERVER=" + DBServer + ";" + "DATABASE=" + DBName + ";" + "UID=" + UName + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + PWord + ";";
    }
 }
```

Btw. I would use ConnectionStringBuilder classes?

```
static string conString
{
     get
     {
         var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
         builder.Server = DBServer;
         builder.UserID = UName;
         builder.Password = PWord;
         builder.Database = DBName;
         return builder.ToString();
     }
}
```

For populating the Fields you could either create properties, too

```
public string DBServer { get { return Properties.Settings.Default.DBServer } }
```

or (since ApplicationSettingsBase already implement INotifyPropertyChanged) you can create a new File `Settings.partial.cs` with this content

```
internal sealed partial class Settings
{
    internal Settings()
    {
        this.PropertyChanged += Settings_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void Settings_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("DBServer"))
            EbayListing.DBServer = this.DBServer;
        else if (e.PropertyName.Equals("DBName"))
            EbayListing.DBName = this.DBName;
    }
}
```

Anyway, I would suggest you drop the whole concept of your static variables completly and create a method inside `EbayListing`

```
private MySqlConnection CreateConnection()
{
     var builder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
     builder.Server = Properties.Settings.Default.DBServer,
     builder.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.UName,
     builder.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.PWord, 
     builder.Database = Properties.Settings.Default.DBName
     return new MySqlConnection(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Since the user set the value of `DBServer`, `UName`, `PWord`, `DBName` when declaring those static fields, they only assign first time and they will not change if `Settings` change

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I added some more code.on how to solve your problem.